# Compressing and decompressing text which results numeric value after compression in java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.HashMap;
import java.io.Set;
class Hema
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        int c = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        //it is for entering the string
        System.out.println("Enter the sentence");

        String sentence = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
        //After entering the string we have to split the sentences into words
        System.out.println("Words in the given sentence are :");
        //After splitting we have to display the value,keys pairs
        for (String word:words)
        {
            map.put(words, c++);

        }
        print(map);
        //by using this maps we have to display the keys as a compressed one
        for (int key: keys)
        {
            System.out.println(key);
        }
        //after compression by using the keys we have to display the values of the keys as the entered text
        Set<String> keys = map.keySet();
        for (String key: keys)
        {
            System.out.println("Value of " + key + " is: " + map.get(key));
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting this error when i am trying to compile my code

```
illegal character: '\u00a0'
    for (String word : words) 
    ^
```

Can anyone help me regarding this problem

Comment: That is a non breaking space, with the UTF8 value of A0. Replace it with a normal space

Comment: Hema, this code seems not compilable on my end. 
imports are different but this is ok i can deal with it.
line 'for (int key : keys) { ' uses keys which is later on being declared and used.
above code to the extend i understand does not compress something. Simply puts in a map the last possition of a word.
Also method print() i cannot understand where it comes from.

Could you please provide  us with a brief description of what you are trying to accomplish or try to provide with a compilable code part (if possible) so that we can help?

Comment: if i give 
hema is studying hema is good
then the output should be:
hema-1
is-2
studying-3
good-4
compressed text will be:
1 2 3 1 2 4

Answer (score 1):

You have many mistakes :-

1. import `java.io.HashMap;` is wrong it is `import java.util.HashMap;`.
2. `map.put(words,c++);` is wrong it should be `map.put(word, c++);`.
3. In `print(map);` , function `print()` is not defined better use   `System.out.println(map);`.
4. `for(int key: keys)` is wrong it should be `for (String key : map.keySet())` .
5. You don't `Set` to implement this code , You can directly use `map.keySet()`  .
6. Code is not properly intended.

Try this code :-

```
import java.util.*;
class Hema {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        int c = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        // it is for entering the string
        System.out.println("Enter the sentence");

        String sentence = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
        // After entering the string we have to split the sentences into words
        System.out.println("Words in the given sentence are :");
        // After splitting we have to display the value,keys pairs
        for (String word : words) {
            map.put(word, c++);

        }
        System.out.println(map);
        // by using this maps we have to display the keys as a compressed one
        for (String key : map.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(key);
        }
        // after compression by using the keys we have to display the values of the keys
        // as the entered text
        for (String key : map.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("Value of " + key + " is: " + map.get(key));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output :-**

```
Enter the sentence
one two three
Words in the given sentence are :
{one=0, two=1, three=2}
one
two
three
Value of one is: 0
Value of two is: 1
Value of three is: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your code I can see following mistake:

```
 for(String word:words)
    {
        map.put(words,c++);
}
```

**words** needs to be **word**.
     Set keys = map.keySet();
needs to be moved above

```
 for(int key: keys)
    {
        System.out.println(key);
    }
```

And the loop needs to iterate over **String**, not **int**

Comment: This is almost no improvement to the code. As after this there'll be still many compile errors left

Comment: Sorry was still checking some more, just fixed all the comile errors.

Comment: i have to print the numbers with out repeatition

Comment: if i give 
hema is studying hema is good
then the output should be:
hema-1
is-2
studying-3
good-4
compressed text will be:
1 2 3 1 2 4

Answer (score 0):

I have suggested few changes in your code :

```
for(String word:words){
        //here word will be in put method as keys not words
        map.put(word,c++);

    }

    //after compression by using the keys we have to display the values of the keys as the entered text
    Set<String> keys = map.keySet();
    //to print values in set
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(keys));

    for(String key: keys){
        System.out.println("Value of "+key+" is: "+map.get(key));
    }

    //use this way to print map 
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(map));
    //by using this maps we have to display the keys as a compressed one
    for(String key: keys){
        //to print key 
        System.out.println(key);
        //to print value
        System.out.println(map.get(key));
    }
```

*output : 
Enter the sentence
hema is studying hema is good 
Words in the given sentence are :
[[is, hema, good, studying]]
Value of is is: 4
Value of hema is: 3
Value of good is: 5
Value of studying is: 2
[{is=4, hema=3, good=5, studying=2}]
is
4
hema
3
good
5
studying
2*